# Paste another column's value as a name of another existing variable to evaluate within dplyr::case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

EDITED VERSION:
Example data

```
df <- data.frame (id = c("215","273","43","50","58"), 
                  to_modif = c("M30","M30","M24","M24","M24"),
                  hlp_vac = c("Vacation4","Vacation4","Vacation4","Vacation4","Vacation4"),
                  hlp_imm = c("Imm4-Imm5","Imm5-Imm6", "Imm4-Imm5","Imm4-Imm5","Imm4-Imm5"),
                  earlier = c("Vacation","Infection","Vacation","Vacation","Vacation"),
                  later = c("Infection","Vacation","Infection","Infection","Infection"),
                  date_Vacation4 = as.Date(c("2022-12-08", "2022-12-12", "2022-04-25", "2022-11-04", "2022-04-28")),
                  date_Vacation5 = as.Date(c(NA,NA,"2022-12-16",NA,NA )),
                  date_infection_m24 = as.Date (c(NA,NA,"2022-09-07", "2022-07-06" ,"2022-10-15")),
                  date_infection_m30 = as.Date (c("2022-12-12" ,"2022-12-20", NA,NA,NA)))
```

There are five subjects, each one has dates (one or more) for infection (date_infection_m24 and m30), and vacation dates (one or more) (date_Vacation4 or 5).

I want to compare for each subject his date_infection and date_Vacation to verify which one was earlier and if necessary to correct the columns "earlier" and "later". Columns "hlp_vac" and "hlp_inf" contain information on which column from date_infection and date_Vacation we should compare for each subject.

For that, I want to dynamically paste for each subject values from columns "hlp_vac" and "hlp_inf" to obtain full column names for date_Vacation (4 or 5) and date_infection (m24 or m30) to evaluate.
The problem is that the case_when seems to return false when the call should be true

Here is one example of the attempt:

```
   df %>% mutate(earlier.original = earlier,
                 earlier = case_when (hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & (paste0("date_",hlp_vac) < paste0("date_infection_",tolower(to_modif))) ~ "vac"
                                   ),
                 
                 what_should_I_get_for_earlier = case_when (id == "215" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m30 ~ "vac",
                                                         id == "43" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m24 ~ "vac",
                                                         id == "50" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m24 ~ "vac",
                                                         id == "58" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m24 ~ "vac"
                                                ))
```

The output I get seems to return all FALSE, and it shouldn't (I added the column what_should_I_get_for_earlier to show what I would like to obtain).

[image: case_when output]

If we look for example the subject 215, we should compare his date_Vacation4 and date_infection_m30 (as defined in columns hlp_vac and hlp_inf).
As called in case_when, it should evaluate if date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m30, i.e. 2022-12-08 < 2022-12-12 (dates are in YMD format) is true. However case_when returns FALSE (so output all NA) even though the statement is true.

More apsurd, if I return the comparison sign it returns TRUE, and the output is like this:

```
   df %>% mutate(earlier.original = earlier,
                 earlier = case_when (hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & (paste0("date_",hlp_vac) > paste0("date_infection_",tolower(to_modif))) ~ "vac"
                                   ),
                 
                 what_should_I_get_for_earlier = case_when (id == "215" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m30 ~ "vac",
                                                         id == "43" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m24 ~ "vac",
                                                         id == "50" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m24 ~ "vac",
                                                         id == "58" & hlp_imm == "Imm4-Imm5" & date_Vacation4 < date_infection_m24 ~ "vac"
                                                ))
```

[image: output after reverse comparison sign]

I have also tried to use !!!sym or get to take the column values, nothing worked.

Thank you in advance for any help or advice!

Comment: Can you be clear which line in the output should be different? It looks like in none of the examples you provided is the date of "vac" less than the date of "inf". In that case your `case_when` is just returning `earlier.orig` so nothing is changing.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for pointing this out, and actually I have overseen this one while I was creating the simplified example. I have edited my question so that it resembles more of the actual data and tried to better explain the problem. Do you think that you might have the solution to this one? Thank you again